# How to get the detail of last call in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

is it possible to get detail of last dialed call?

I want the call duration of last dialed number programmatically.

Answer (score 5):

No way. Simply it's not possible in IOS unless jail-broken. Apple is really concerned with their security policy. So they won't give these details.

Call duration also cannot be fetch.

**Core Telephony framework**  is mainly used for call event monitoring(call state),fetching carrier details,etc. But you cant fetch call log using Core Telephony

In previous IOS versions, you can obtain the call history by accessing **SQLite db**. But apple fixed that now. Anyway you can try to access the DB. But there is only minor chance to get the access and even if you can access that, your app will be rejected in appstore.

Comment: is it possible to use core telephony framework for it.?

Comment: no.we cant fetch that by using core telephony framework. i already tried same thing for one of my app